# adding an icon in front of a input field without disrupting the flow of the form

Tags: html, css

OK so, I have an icon that when I put in front of an input it is pushing the input to the right by 5 pixels or so therefore, throwing the fields out of visual alignment. Is there a style I can throw on :before input or something that can make the icon move over the left a bit?  My HTML looks like so:

```
<li>
 <label>Date</label>
 <img src="img/cal.png"/>
 <input type="text"/>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just whitespace?  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: No it wasn't but thanks for the article.

Comment: You do understand that `img` and `input` are both inline elements, right?  There's no way the "5px" space could be there without it being either whitespace between inline elements or because of some other styling that you put there (padding/margin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a css negative margin on the `img` element:

```
<li>
   <label>Date</label>
   <img src="img/cal.png" style="margin-left: -5px;" />
   <input type="text"/>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably from the implicit space between inline elements and carriage returns in the markup. Try this markup formatting "trick"

```
<li>
 <label>Date</label>
 <img src="img/cal.png"
 /><input type="text"/>
</li>
```

or go all inline

```
<li><label>Date</label><img src="img/cal.png" /><input type="text"/></li>
```

I made a JSFiddle that [demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/8QJZa/).

Comment: Why so? this only solves spacing problems on old IE versions.

Comment: @Ulflander not an old IE issue, this is part of HTML.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8QJZa/ or read the article mentioned in the first comment under the question

Answer (score 0):

You could resize the text box itself:

```
<input type="text" style="width:40px" />
```

Comment: avoid inline styling when possible, this would be better as a rule in a style sheet or at least <style> tags in the header

Comment: Not if he just wants to change the size of one of the input boxes, it'd have to be a class or an id which at that point you might as well just use inline since it'll save a few bytes of data.